# Detect scroll-event on every parent-element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, directive

I have a directive which should detect a scroll-event on every parent element. The scrollable element could be div with `overflow:scroll` or the browser-window itself. So this solution does not work in all cases:

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() { ... });
```

Comment: What's not working? What do you mean it works sometimes? YOu need to give us some context and something to work with

Comment: This solution doesn´t work if the directive is in a div-container with overflow:scroll

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. Here it is:

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('*')).bind("scroll", $scope.myFunction);
```

Comment: Not really efficient.

Comment: It's a very bad idea. Super inefficient. If you really need to do this I'd loop through each parent container and check their overflow-y value for 'scroll' even then I'd consider doing something else with my life

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the scroll event at the capture phase.  To do this, pass `true` as the third parameter of `addEventListener`:

```js
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log('scrolling');
}, true);
```

Your example works when I replace your javascript with the code above, and there's no jQuery dependancy.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add some specific height for the div elements to scroll

For example:

```
div{
  height: 350px;    // Specify div height as you want
  overflow: scroll;
}
```